# Can Visual Studio read a set of include file paths from a text file for the Additional Include Directories?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to figure out how to get Visual Studio to read a set of include files from a text file.

For example, I would like to create a text file called IncludePaths.txt that contains a list of include paths such as "/I ../../header"

I would then tell Visual Studio reference this file.

I believe you could do this by adding @IncludePaths.txt to the Additional Include Directory, but I cannot get  this to work. I have seen this done in projects I have worked on in the past but I can't find any documentation or figure out the trick.

Answer (score 0):

After a little more research and talking to a couple of other developers, I figured out the "trick"

1) Create a file called IncludePaths.txt next to my project file.
2) Add your include paths to this file...

```
/I "..\..\..\..\open\common\include"
/I "..\..\..\common\include"
/I "..\..\"
```

3) Go to Properties -> C++ -> Command Line
4) Under "Additional Options" add @IncludePaths.txt

Alternatively, you can use custom properties to get this to work too.